# What does it mean for an automorphism to centralize a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$. What does it mean for an automorphism $\sigma\colon G\to G$ to centralize $H$?

The context I have is that if $\sigma$ centralizes $H$, then the map $x\mapsto \sigma(x)x^{-1}$ sends $H$ to the identity, which would mean $\sigma(h)=h$ for $h\in H$, so does it mean $\sigma$ fixes $H$ pointwise, or something more general?

Comment: Yes, it simply means that $\sigma$ fixes $H$ pointwise.

Comment: @DanShved Thanks.